# istio tracking network request and finding point of failure

Tags: istio

Using `Istio 1.2.10-gke.3` on gke

`curl -v -HHost:user.domain.com --resolve user.domain.com:443:$gatewayIP https://user.domain.com/auth -v -k`

return a 503 after tls verification

```
< date: Tue, 19 May 2020 20:50:29 GMT
< server: istio-envoy
```

Now I want to track the request and identify the first point of failure by tracing the logs of the components involved and resolve the issue

The logs of the istio-ingressgateway pod show nothing. After getting a shell on the pod, I do a `top` and see an `envoy` process running, however I don't see any logs for the envoy in `/var/log/`

What am I missing? Am I looking at the wrong place? Or do I need to read the code of the framework to be able to use it?
I need to find out which link in the request processing chain broke first and the reason so that the same can be fixed

Comment: There are several reasons why You could be getting the 503 error. Do You have mTLS enabled? Is the service in question properly injected and all containers are running. After that check if the deployment manifest have a port that is properly "named" like mentioned [here](https://istio.io/docs/ops/configuration/traffic-management/protocol-selection/).

Comment: yes there can be many, i am looking for some kind of component logs that say `could not connect to service named blah because of invalid tls or network failure or ...`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some useful links to istio documentation for debugging error `503`:

Istio documentation for [envoy access logs](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/)

Istio documentation for [Connectivity troubleshooting](https://istio.io/docs/ops/common-problems/network-issues/).

Useful envoy debugging tool [`istioctl`](https://istio.io/docs/ops/diagnostic-tools/proxy-cmd/).

> ```
> $ istioctl proxy-status
> ```

Also one rare case where [error 503](https://istio.io/docs/ops/best-practices/traffic-management/#avoid-503-errors-while-reconfiguring-service-routes) could be present.

This error could also be present if envoy sidecar proxy has issues or did not properly inject itself to deployment pod. Or when there are `mTLS` miss-configurations.

Hope it helps.